# Find parameter $m$ knowing that the values of the function are in a interval of length 4

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please give me a hint on how to find the parameter $m$ knowing that the function values are in an interval of length $4$:

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2 + mx + 1 }{x^2-x+1}.$$

Comment: Hint:  $\frac {x^2+mx+1}{x^2-x+1}=1+(m+1)\frac {x}{x^2-x+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The critic points of $f$ are at $1$ and $-1$. We can show that in such points the absolute extrema are reached, giving us
$$\left|f(1)-f(-1)\right|=4$$